# Combine two Private Sub Worksheet_Change

Tags: excel, vba

I am using VBA to check a value of a cell and call an email module to email if the cell's value is more than a value.

I want to check multiple cells but understand that it is not possible to have two Private Sub Worksheet_Change in VBA. What is the best way to check multiple cells?

Here is the code I am using;

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 10 Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is another if possible I would like to combine into the one Sub

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("B1"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 20 Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not put both `If Not Application.Intersect...` blocks into the same Sub, one after the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about doing this?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call MailAlert(Target, "A1", 10)
    Call MailAlert(Target, "B1", 20)
End Sub

Private Sub MailAlert(ByVal Target As Range, ByVal Address As String, ByVal Value As Integer)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Address), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value > Value Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I was getting a syntax error and need to add a Call before Mailalert but it is now working.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Select Case Taget.Address

  Case "$A$1" 'This will make sure its just one cell and its A1          
      If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 10 Then         
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook         
      End If     

  Case "$B$1" 'This will make sure its just one cell and its B1
      If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 20 Then         
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook         
      End If 

  'Case ... whatever else you want.

End Select
End Sub
```

There may be more efficient ways, but this is what first came to mind. Hope this answers your question.